# How to save data from a Lambda function into a S3 when we have too much incoming per millisecond?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I have a process that publishes data into a IoT-Core and that triggers a Lambda function that inserts the payload into an Amazon S3 bucket.

I have a process that send around 1.2 million records in some seconds, and when I check in the bucket I see I have lost around 10% of the data. If I set a sleep in the Lambda function it goes beyond 15 minutes.

What is the solution for this scenario?

Comment: What do you mean by "1,2M"? Events, data size? And why put a sleep in your lambda?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your requirement is to capture the events coming into IoT-Core and save them to Amazon S3.

It also sounds like your Lambda functions are being throttled due to hitting [concurrency limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html) and data is being lost. By default, there is a [limit of 10,000 concurrent AWS Lambda functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html). This could potentially be fixed by requesting an increase in the maximum number of concurrent functions.

Here is a diagram from [How AWS IoT works](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/aws-iot-how-it-works.html):

[image: AWS IoT]

As shown in the digram, the **Rules engine** can actually be used to [send data to Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-rule-actions.html#s3-rule) without requiring Lambda. However, this creates a separate object in Amazon S3 for every message.

If you wish to **combine messages** together, you can [Write to Kinesis Data Firehose Using AWS IoT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/writing-with-iot.html). Firehose will buffer the data by time or size, and then output multiple messages to an Amazon S3 object. This could be a good way to handle large volumes of data, and it also makes it easier to work with the resulting objects in S3 because there are less objects created. This makes them faster to query and process later (eg with Amazon Athena).

Answer (score 0):

Going from IoT-Core rule direct to a Lambda can be fragile.

You can use Kinesis to buffer the data or Firehose to stream it directly to S3. These are standard patterns that AWS recommend for IoT in the AWS Well-Architected framework (https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/architecture/AWS-IoT-Lens.pdf).